# MongoDb search performance

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to know why the follow search in mongo db (C#) would take 50 seconds to execute.

I followed the basic idea of http://calv.info/indexing-schemaless-documents-in-mongo/

I have 100,000 records in a collection(captures). On each document I have a SearchTerm Collection

```
public class SearchTerm
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

public class Capture
{
    //Some other fields
    public IList<SearchTerm> SearchTerms { get; set; }
}
```

I have also defined a index like so

```
var capturesCollection = database.GetCollection<Capture>("captures");
capturesCollection.CreateIndex("SearchTerms.Key", "SearchTerms.Value");
```

But the following query takes 50 seconds to execute

```
var query = Query.Or(Query.And(Query.EQ("SearchTerms.Key", "ClientId"), Query.EQ("SearchTerms.Value", selectedClient.Id)), Query.And(Query.EQ("SearchTerms.Key", "CustomerName"), Query.EQ("SearchTerms.Value", "Jan")));
var selectedCapture = capturesCollection.Find(query).ToList();
```

**Edit**: As asked my explain:

```
clauses: [{ "cursor" : "BtreeCursor SearchTerms.Key_1_SearchTerms.Value_1", "isMultiKey" : true, "n" : 10003, "nscannedObjects" : 100000, "nscanned" : 100000, "scanAndOrder" : false, "indexOnly" : false, "nChunkSkips" : 0, "indexBounds" : { "SearchTerms.Key" : [["ClientId", "ClientId"]], "SearchTerms.Value" : [[{ "$minElement" : 1 }, { "$maxElement" : 1 }]] } }, { "cursor" : "BtreeCursor SearchTerms.Key_1_SearchTerms.Value_1", "isMultiKey" : true, "n" : 70328, "nscannedObjects" : 90046, "nscanned" : 211653, "scanAndOrder" : false, "indexOnly" : false, "nChunkSkips" : 0, "indexBounds" : { "SearchTerms.Key" : [["CustomerName", "CustomerName"]], "SearchTerms.Value" : [[{ "$minElement" : 1 }, { "$maxElement" : 1 }]] } }]
cursor: QueryOptimizerCursor
n: 73219
nscannedObjects: 190046
nscanned: 311653
nscannedObjectsAllPlans: 190046
nscannedAllPlans: 311653
scanAndOrder: false
nYields: 2436
nChunkSkips: 0
millis: 5196
server: piro-pc:27017
filterSet: false
stats: { "type" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS", "works" : 311655, "yields" : 2436, "unyields" : 2436, "invalidates" : 0, "advanced" : 73219, "needTime" : 238435, "needFetch" : 0, "isEOF" : 1, "children" : [{ "type" : "OR", "works" : 311655, "yields" : 2436, "unyields" : 2436, "invalidates" : 0, "advanced" : 73219, "needTime" : 238435, "needFetch" : 0, "isEOF" : 1, "dupsTested" : 80331, "dupsDropped" : 7112, "locsForgotten" : 0, "matchTested_0" : 0, "matchTested_1" : 0, "children" : [{ "type" : "FETCH", "works" : 100001, "yields" : 2436, "unyields" : 2436, "invalidates" : 0, "advanced" : 10003, "needTime" : 89997, "needFetch" : 0, "isEOF" : 1, "alreadyHasObj" : 0, "forcedFetches" : 0, "matchTested" : 10003, "children" : [{ "type" : "IXSCAN", "works" : 100000, "yields" : 2436, "unyields" : 2436, "invalidates" : 0, "advanced" : 100000, "needTime" : 0, "needFetch" : 0, "isEOF" : 1, "keyPattern" : "{ SearchTerms.Key: 1, SearchTerms.Value: 1 }", "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['SearchTerms.Key']: [\"ClientId\", \"ClientId\"], field #1['SearchTerms.Value']: [MinKey, MaxKey]", "isMultiKey" : 1, "yieldMovedCursor" : 0, "dupsTested" : 100000, "dupsDropped" : 0, "seenInvalidated" : 0, "matchTested" : 0, "keysExamined" : 100000, "children" : [] }] }, { "type" : "FETCH", "works" : 211654, "yields" : 2436, "unyields" : 2436, "invalidates" : 0, "advanced" : 70328, "needTime" : 141325, "needFetch" : 0, "isEOF" : 1, "alreadyHasObj" : 0, "forcedFetches" : 0, "matchTested" : 70328, "children" : [{ "type" : "IXSCAN", "works" : 211653, "yields" : 2436, "unyields" : 2436, "invalidates" : 0, "advanced" : 90046, "needTime" : 121607, "needFetch" : 0, "isEOF" : 1, "keyPattern" : "{}", "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['SearchTerms.Key']: [\"CustomerName\", \"CustomerName\"], field #1['SearchTerms.Value']: [MinKey, MaxKey]", "isMultiKey" : 1, "yieldMovedCursor" : 0, "dupsTested" : 211653, "dupsDropped" : 121607, "seenInvalidated" : 0, "matchTested" : 0, "keysExamined" : 211653, "children" : [] }] }] }] }
```

Comment: Please run [.explain()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) on the query (more detailed instructions in alernerdev's answer) and post the output for us.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting the explain. Let's address the problems one at a time.

First, I don't think this query does what you think it does / want it to do. Let me show you by example using the mongo shell. Your query, translated into the shell, is

```
{ "$or" : [
    { "$and" : [
        { "SearchTerms.Key" : "ClientId" }, 
        { "SearchTerms.Value" : "xxx" }
    ]},
    { "$and" : [
        { "SearchTerms.Key" : "CustomerName" },     
        { "SearchTerms.Value" : "Jan" }
    ]}
]}
```

This query finds documents where either some `Key` has the value "ClientId" and some `Value` has the value "xxx" or some `Key` has the value "CustomerName" and some `Value` the value "Jan". *The key and the value don't need to be part of the same array element*. For example, the following document matches your query

```
{ "SearchTerms" : [
        { "Key" : "ClientId", "Value" : 691 }, 
        { "Key" : "banana", "Value" : "xxx" }
    ]
}
```

I'm guessing your desired behavior is to match exactly the documents that contain the `Key` and `Value` in the same array element. The [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#specify-multiple-criteria-for-array-elements) operator is the tool for the job:

```
{ "$or" : [
    { "SearchTerms" : { "$elemMatch" : { "Key" : "ClientId", "Value" : "xxx" } } },
    { "SearchTerms" : { "$elemMatch" : { "Key" : "CustomerName", "Value" : "Jan" } } }
]}
```

Second, I don't think this schema is what you are looking for. You don't describe your use case so I can't be confident, but the situation described in that blog post is a very rare situation where you need to store and search on *arbitrary* key-value pairs that can change from one document to the next. This is like letting users put in custom metadata. Almost no applications want or need to do this. It looks like your application is storing information about customers, probably for an internal system. You should be able to define a [data model](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/) for your customers that looks like

```
{
    "CustomerId" : 1234,
    "CustomerName" : "Jan",
    "ClientId" : "xpj1234",
    ...
}
```

This will simplify and improve things dramatically. I think the wires got crossed here because sometimes people call MongoDB "schemaless" and the blog post talks about "schemaless" documents. The blog post really is talking about schemaless documents where you don't know what is going to go in there. Most applications should know pretty much exactly what the general structure of the documents in a collection will be.

Finally, I think on the basis of this we can disregard the issue with the slow query for now. Feel free to ask another question or edit this one with extra explanation if you need more help or if the problem doesn't go away once you've taken into account what I've said here.

Comment: Thanks for the help. On the first point you are correct. I want the results that elemMatch would give. However regarding your second point. I have exactly the situation were I do NOT know what data the documents will contain (this is due to the fact that data is collected using workflows created by third parties). I therefore opted to use the model as suggested through the link. I am guessing changing my query to elemMatch will not solve my performance issue?

Comment: In the other post you also commented on the idea was to some how discover what new fields have been added and then index those fields as new documents contain new fields however given the dynamic nature of my data I presume the pattern used in the post is the better approach? (I specifically chose MongoDb due to its ability to handle unstructured data)

Answer (score 0):

1) Please take a look at mongodb log file and see whats the query that gets generated against the database.
2) Enter that query into mongo shell and add ".explain()" at the end -- and see if your index is actually being used (does it say Basic Cursor or Btree Cursor ?)
3) If your index is used, whats the value of "nscanned" attribute?  Perhaps your index does not have enough "value diversity" in it?

Comment: 311653. Not sure what this tells me though. See my edit

Comment: What this tells you is that your index, although is used, is inefficient.  If your index was efficient, your nScanned value would be tiny (single digit, perhaps).  Imagine storing People, and indexing on eye color.  Although you can get to the "hazel" bucket quickly, you then have to scan millions of records looking for the person you are looking for.  You have a similar situation. See this for more info: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-3187